# Is it possible to display a subreport without calling the main report?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I faced a question in an interview:

> Is there a way to display the contents of a subreport without calling the main report?

I tried searching for that over the net, but didn't find any answer.

Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 1):

A sub-report is by definition a report. So the answer is to call the sub-report instead of the main report with the parameter values required.

If you are using a reporting services server and you have provided datasets or value sets for your parameters in the original sub - report this process is much more straightforward.